# Particles stop emitting too early (bug?)

Tags: particles

I am pretty new to Blender.

I have a cube that is suppose to emit particles over a course of ~1000 frames. But the whole number over particles gets emitted in the first frame. This happens without the influence of turbulence fields, since I turned them *Off* for my cube via field weight settings/effector collection.

I have two Bevel modifiers chained before my particle system but it doesn't seem to make a difference for the emitting problem (other than turning on use modifier stack).

The reason I think it might be a bug is that sometimes when I switch settings - for example switching emit source from faces to vertices - I get the normal result of slowly emitting particles. However even then the cube stops emitting after ~200 frames instead of 1000.

[image: before emitting start frame 700]

before emitting start frame 700

[image: after emitting start frame 733]

after emitting start frame 733 (cube is moving downwards)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: did u ever delete your cache?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it seems to work for me.  I don't see any bevel *results* in your screencap.  Perhaps these setting are too fine?

Here from my experiment frame 1:

[image]

and frame 14, as the particles stop emitting from the system.  I see that all faces of the bevel'd object are being used.

[image]

for comparison:  [image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented a workaround, using a seperate object as an emitter for the particles and placing it inside my cube.